# Contents of <select> disappear when page is resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have 3 html selects in a row on my page that normally display fine. However, when the page is resized below a certain width, the contents of all of the selects disappear. You can view both states here:

[Normal Width Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjOeG.png)

[Resized Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKPi5.png)

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and these are just normal select tags with no additional styling or Javascript. Does anyone know how to prevent the contents of my select tag from disappearing when the page is resized? Using a different version of Bootstrap is not an option. I'm stuck with 2.3.2.

Also, if I keep decreasing the width, the contents of the selects come back. I'm guessing it has something to do with bootstrap and responsiveness etc. but I don't know enough about Bootstrap to pin down the exact cause.

I was able to use Chrome Developer Tools and found that when the text in the select disappear, if I disable the font-size in the following:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 481px)
label, button, select, .uiGrid.table td, .uiGrid.table th {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

The text in the select reappears. Unfortunately that bit of CSS is defined in a shared library that I do not control.

As requested, here is the code that I use to add the selects to the page:

```
            <div class="pull-left">
            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
                <div class="btn-group">                    
                    <select class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select 1</option>
                        <option>Value 2</option>
                        <option>Value 3</option>
                        <option>Value 4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <select class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select 2</option>
                        <option>Value 2</option>
                        <option>Value 3</option>
                        <option>Value 4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <select class="input-medium">
                        <option>Select 3</option>
                        <option>Value 2</option>
                        <option>Value 3</option>
                        <option>Value 4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: this site if for code-related questions. how are we supposed to help when you didn't post any code.

Comment: Control looks like it can't cope with text width and shunts the text off somewhere. Can you post some code, peeps on here prefer that sort of thing.

Comment: The code you posted works fine on its own - http://www.bootply.com/y12Dmqo08a so it has to be other CSS which affects this element. Analyse your code in web dev tools in a browser. Does it happen on some certain viewport widths?

Comment: @robjez, yes, if I keep resizing and make the width smaller the contents of the selects eventually come back.

Comment: It will be had to say what it is without you recreating this issue (with all remaining code) on ie. Codepen.io . Besides of that - capture the exact viewport width when this starts to occur. Do you have a media queries bound to this exact value?

Comment: @robjez, see my update to the question. It appears that there is a media query in a shared library that I do not control.

Comment: see my answer - did you try to disable/switch off that rule in developer tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the hammer and override the `media query` stuff in your `CSS`:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 481px)
label, button, select, .uiGrid.table td, .uiGrid.table th {
    font-size: (whatever value you need ie. 24px) !important;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work as is. I was able to get a workable solution by using `.btn-group select {
    font-size: 13px !important;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yup, makes sense, in order of overriding selector you need to come up with a selector of higher specificity in your case `.btn-group select` is more specific than only `select`, which comes from 3rd party stylesheet. In this case, you might even not need of`!important` at the end. Your welcome!